# Select friends that aren't fan of a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a Facebook application and I need to select all my friends that **are not** fan of a specific page: any idea on how can I build the query?

**UPDATE**

I apologise, I'll try to be much more clear.

In my application I want to select all the friend that are not fan of a page, because I want to invite them to **I Like** the page.

Looking into the developer guide I read that is not possible to execute the SQL **NOT IN**, so using the FQL how is it possible to retrieve those friends who **Not Like** the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this FQL query:

`SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND uid IN (SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND page_id='YOUR_PAGE_ID')=''`

Edit:
You must has `user_likes` and `friends_likes` permissions in order to get this data

Comment: Hi @yaron-uliel, thanks for you help but this query doesn't work, I still to continue to retrieve all the friends.

Comment: it does work if you have the `user_likes,friends_likes` permissions - I've tried it in the Graph API Explorer tool

Comment: Hi @yaron-uliel, right I've added `user_likes,friends_likes` and it works great! In case there are a lot of friends is there a way to implement a pagination?

Comment: read this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/